# rotating images inside of div separately

Tags: css

new to css here, I have bunch of images that I want to rotate/spin them.

```
.images_div{
  position: absolute;
  top: 1%;
  left: -2%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  margin:-60px 0 0 -60px;
  -webkit-animation:spin 150s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:spin 150s linear infinite;
  animation:spin 150s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

I use the code above for spin the div that includes the images.
the problem is well it spins the div not the images inside of it, but I want the images not to move and each of them just spin separately.
I'm guess using the code above for each one of the images is not the right way to do this? so How should I do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Give a class to the images, and not to the divs. Then apply this css to the images using your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following styles to img tags inside the div

```
.images_div img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 150s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 150s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 150s linear infinite;
}
```

```css
.images_div img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 150s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 150s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 150s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="images_div">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50">
</div>
```